# How to pass data from react native to node.js (express)

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

How to pass data from react native to node.js (express)?

I'm working on a react native and nodejs (express) but can't figure out how to exchange data between them.

Comment: By creating api in nodejs and hitting the endpints in react native

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to make an endpoint to node.js server for example post /postdata and make a fetch call from react native

Comment: Can you explain more in details what to do?

Comment: Your node app looks something like that const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/', function requestHandler(req, res) { //do something with that data
});

const server = await app.listen(3000);     just make fetch call from react native, like shown here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch